# How to Group By Distinct in EF

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I need to translate this SQL to Linq for use with Entity Framework:

```
SELECT TheDate, COUNT(DISTINCT IPAddress) as Count 
FROM TheTable Group By TheDate
Order By TheDate
```

The difficulty is the Count(Distinct IPAddress).

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from x in db.TheTable
group x by x.TheDate into g
orderby g.Key
select new
{
    TheDate = g.Key,
    DistinctIPCount = g.Select(x => x.IPAddress).Distinct().Count()
}
```

Comment: This looks good, but when I try it, VS12 gives me a compile error on the last line: Anon type project should be simple name or member access expression.

Comment: See edit. The fields of the anonymous type just need to be named since they are of the same type.